# laravel login for ever

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

In Laravel when a user logged in, I want to stay log in, while my user logout 
what should I do?

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

I change to:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('1')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the remember flag to always be true then replace:

```
return $this->guard()->attempt(
    $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('1')
);
```

with:

```
return $this->guard()->attempt(
    $this->credentials($request), true
);
```

The filled method is simply checking whether there is a value in the request that isn't empty an empty string, so `$request->filled('1')` is checking for a input item called `1` and then checking to see if it is "filled" or not.